# Htaccess / Mod rewrite, redirecting to landing page when IP different than mine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect all the requests to /landing when the IP is different than mine and when the user is not already on /landing and when the request is not a picture of /landing.

I've tried with this but no luck and I'm not sure why:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# LANDING PAGE FOR IP DIFFERENT THAN MINE
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=22.22.22.22
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/landing/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/landing/^.*\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$
RewriteRule .* /landing/index.php [L]
```

Comment: What you want to do. render some page for your IP and landing page for others. Right??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^(22\.22\.22\.22)$
RewriteRule ^/* http://www.domain.com/landing/index.php [L]
```

Check this [link](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html) for details (Block a Specific IP Address section)

You can negate the condition by adding exclamation mark

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^22\.22\.22\.22$
```

If it still don't work try turning on logging while troubleshooting your rewrites. (Level 9 will give you the most detailed logging)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteLog /tmp/log.txt
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

This will log every step Apache takes while churning your request through mod_rewrite.